# Backbone.js model (2)

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

im using backbone JS and im having troubles showing the  data from the MODEL. 
can anyone know how this works? TIA

VIEW.JS -

```
    render: function() {
             ///EDITED TO SIMPLIFY      

            var toModel = new tModel();//tModel is the name of the model    
    console.log(toModel.get('data'));//?? UNDEFINE


  }
```

MODEL.JS  --

```
    data:[
        { text: "Google", href: "http://google.com" },
        { text: "Facebook", href: "http://facebook.com" },
        { text: "Youtube", href: "http://youtube.com" }
    ],
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to diagnose. I could see how the answers given could both be right depending on the rest of your model and view code. Could you supply us with a little bit more? For example, although it seems we're assuming you're data is a model attribute, is it? Or is it a property of the object? `model.get('data')` vs. `model.data`

Comment: is it clear enough now? sorry guys . i've just started using backbone JS

Comment: Basically @StuR did it for you. ;-) If that is the structure of your view and model, then his is a correct answer and thorough answer / complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g3U7j/6/

model.js

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        data: [
            {
            text: "Google",
            href: "http://google.com"},
        {
            text: "Facebook",
            href: "http://facebook.com"},
        {
            text: "Youtube",
            href: "http://youtube.com"}
        ]
    }
});
```

view.js

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var x = this.model.get('data');
        console.log(x);
    }
});

var View = new MyView({
    model: new MyModel
});​
```

Comment: hmm. thanks for the sample @StuR .  actually i also got it work in 1 JS file only . but since the scripts are in different JS (model.js and view.js) my sample doesn't work

Comment: StuR got the structure. +1 to stur. but it still wont work since the model and view is divided into 2 files. make sense?

Comment: @bones . Make Model class and View class global , remove var, then it work in separate files.

Comment: You might want to make `defaults` a function when you have mutable data like that (i.e. things other than numbers, strings, booleans, ...), otherwise the `defaults` can get accidentally modified; compare http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tGmZR/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tGmZR/4/

Comment: @Stur Got it! thanks everyone.  i Don't know that we can add arrays inside the default.

Answer (score 0):

It's `this.model.get('data')` (drop the capital M in Model which refers to the class and not the instance member).

Also, if you call `render` directly from an event handler, you need to make sure `this` is properly bound to the class instance in the render method (the normal stuff using `that` instead of `this` in javascript; I'm doing this mostly in Coffeescript where it's a bit easier).

Comment: thats a typo. its a modelname that i defined  :)